# Is there a way for items to memorize values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is it possible to create a list with memorized values using excel? I would like to create a excel sheet that keeps track of different tasks(items) and be able to change values depending on how far i have come in the particular activity (this will be displayed in 0% to 100% of the activity completion). Illustrate this with an example shown below;

The excel sheet has one column where i can choose different tasks. If i choose task A information will be taken from another sheet using VLOOKUP and display some information for me to see see, also i can set the task completion to 70%. Next, i change the "choose task" to task B, this gets me the values using from task B and displays them for me. Here i set the task completion to 30% (for task B).
When I choose task A (displaying information for task A), i would like to retrive the 70% task completion that i set for task A before. Is it possible?

One solution for this is to externally set the values for the different tasks in another cell and only use VLOOKUP to get them back. Is there a way to memorize a value (0-100%) for a particular item as i explained?

I was unable to upload a figure, hope it is understandable.

Thanks

Comment: You would have to update the "completion" cell which is being returned by the vlookup formula, either directly on the lookup sheet, or via a macro.

Comment: Overall you are better off using built-in filters rather than vlookup.

Comment: This is the kind of task a simple userform does well. Have a dropdown menu/combo box populated with the tasks/items, and a slider control that adjusts the level of task completion for the selected task. The task completion progress could be stored in the worksheet itself, or as a `Named Range`. Select each task and adjust its completion level in turn. The task completion for each task is updated when the slider moves. Could also be implemented on a worksheet without using a userform.

Comment: The way you describe it, this needs macro/VBA. Btw, you can upload images on any free image hosting site, provide the link and someone here will surely post it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Add an extra sheet . Define the names of cells amd put the 70% in cell a1 , 30% in cell a2 so on

Define cell a1 as taskA
Define cell a2 as taskB

Then on ur main sheet lets say you choosing your task in cell B2

```
=IF(B2="A",taskA,IF(B2="B",taskB,""))
```

Or

```
=IF(B2="A","70%"),IF(B2="B","30%",""))
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-named-cell-references-or-ranges-HP005201536.aspx